# How to: When application updates, automatically clear previous application' s data

Tags: java, android

I have code which is running with preference data. I have very simple boolean control store in preference. When I update my application, I'm seeing that it doesn't clear data and is running with previous data. I have to fix that problem tonight, what is your suggestion about this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Make your application read a "version" value from the preferences. If that version is not there, or is not the same as the current version, then you can clear/update/migrate the preferences to the new version.

Comment: No idea. I got one too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing from iPad, so I can't write more code. I did something that U want to do a longtime ago )))To clear all data use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/486027/ProgrammaticallyplusClearingplusCacheplusinplusAnd). And then in loading activity use something like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE < #version code from preferences#) {
    // clear data
    // save new version code to preferences
}
```

Always when user updates his app, this code will clear data if the application's preferences have no >= version code.